# roots of unity and geometry problem

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, polygons

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uiGN.jpg)

I have managed to do part A but part B's starting point is confusing. If the question stated find the sum of the distance from X to the vertices of the polygon the rest of the question is fine.

But why does mean the sum of XA mean finding the sum of|w-2|

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you provide what you have tried so far? Then it is possible to better help you.

Comment: "The sum of XA" ? I see the sum of all $(XA_k)^2$. Please be precise.

Comment: The square of distance $(XA_k)^2$ is identical to $|z_k-x|^2$ where $z_k=\exp(i 2\pi k/7)$ and $X=2+0i$  ; now use the relationship established in the first question.

Comment: Another way, without using (a). The discrete form of the [parallel axes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem) for $\,n\,$ points $\,A_k\,$ with centroid $\,G\,$ and an arbitrary point $\,X\,$ is $\,\sum_{k=1}^n XA_k^2 = n \cdot XG^2 + \sum_{k=1}^n GA_k^2\,$. For the given heptagon $n = 7$, $G \equiv O$, $GA_k = 1$ and $XG = 2$.

Answer (score 3):

*The first version of this solution was incorrect on its final steps.  An edit was made based on user @dxiv's comments below*.

---

From the first relationship, $|w-2|^2=5-2(w+\bar w)$, if w is a root of unity, we have: $$\sum_{i=1}^7(XA_i)^2=\sum_{i=1}^7[5-2(A_i-\bar A_i)]$$ since every $A_i$ is a root of unity.

So $$S=\sum_{i=1}^7[5-2(A_i-\bar A_i)]=35-4i\Im\Big(\sum_{i=1}^7 A_i\Big)$$

since $z-\bar z=2i\Im(z)$.

But as @dxiv observed in the comments, since the LHS is a real number, we must have $$\Im\Big(\sum_{i=1}^7 A_i\Big)=0$$

Thus, $S=35$.

---

Comment: "*its internal angles are all equal*" $-$ But $\theta_i$ is not the internal angle, it is the argument of $A_i$.

Comment: @dxiv You are correct. I wrote it hastily. I am trying to see if a solution can be salvaged.

Comment: Just use that $\sum A_i = \sum \bar{A_i} = 0$ directly. Or, if you want to stick to $\Im(z)$ note that $z - \bar z = 2\color{red}{i}\,\Im(z)$ and argue that the LHS is known to be real, so the $\Im$ part of the RHS must be $0$.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you! So the sum must be $35$... I messed up $\Im (z)$, forgetting $i$.  I am editing it and attributing the solution to you.

Comment: Looks good now (+1). For verification, it matches the formula in my comment under the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z\in\mathbb C$ and $|z|=1$. See that
$$|z-2|^2 = (z-2)(\overline{z-2})=(z-2)(\overline{z}-\overline{2}) \\ =z\overline{z}-2z-2\overline{z}+4 \\ =|z|^2-2(z+\overline{z})+4 \\ =1+4-4\left(\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}\right) \\ =5-4\Re (z)$$
Which is obviously equal to the Right Hand Side.